# How can I tell if if a type variable inherits from a class?

Tags: java, inheritance, generics

In this situation:

```
// in Bar.java:

public class Bar{
}

// in Foo.java:

public class Foo<T extends Bar> {
  T[] vals;
  public Foo(T[] initVals) {
    vals = initVals;
  }
  public String toString() {
    if (vals != null && T.class.isAssignableFrom(CharSequence.class)) { // <= error
      return Arrays.toString(vals);
    }
    return "T is not an array of character sequences";
  }
}
```

an error occurs on the commented line:

```
cannot select from a type variable
```

**How can I tell if `T` is an array of character sequences?**

Comment: How could T extend Bar, and also be an array?

Comment: @JBNizet you're right. Sorry, I was whipping this up as I had to go.  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. At runtime, all information about `T` is gone. Because of type erasure, at runtime the JVM knows only that `T` is some subclass of `Bar`.

If you have an instance of `T`, you can try with `getClass()`, for example:

```
if (vals != null && 
    vals.length > 0 && 
    vals[0].getClass().isAssignableFrom(someOtherClass)) { ... }
```

Otherwise, you will have to refactor your solution. You can, for example, pass the class of `T` explicitly:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    T[] vals;
    Class<T> clazz;
    public Foo(T[] initVals, Class<T> initClass) {
        vals = initVals;
        clazz = initClass;
    }
    public String toString() {
        if (vals != null && clazz.isAssignableFrom(CharSequence.class)) { ... }
        return "T is not an array of character sequences";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the use of the second solution, since the first approach will work perfectly fine?

Comment: @RohitJain. The second solution is not equivalent to first solution. First, it will also work when `vals[0]` can be `null`. Second, `vals` can actually belong to a subtype of `T[]`, in which case `vals.getClass()` is not the same as "`T[]`".

Answer (score 2):

You can't have something like `T.class`. That's an illegal expression in the first place.

But, what you're looking for is the `Class` instance of your array, which is `vals` with type `T[]`, not the type `T` itself. You should do `vals.getClass()` in that case:

```
public String toString() {
    if (vals != null && vals.getClass().isAssignableFrom(CharSequence[].class)) { 
      return Arrays.toString(vals);
    }
    return "T is not an array of character sequences";
}
```

*P.S:* No idea how that condition is ever going to be true. Since `CharSequence` doesn't extend `Bar`.